# How to override Enterprise Architect cut/paste feature

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there any way to override EA Cut/Paste feature?
If Yes, then how can we achieve this ?
If No, then is there any alternative solution for this?

For example: Consider I have two packages in the Model – Package **Package1** and **Package2**. Under Package1 I have two elements **Element1** and **Element2** and under Package2 I have an element **Element3**.

**Element1** and **Element2** are present under **Diagram1** and **Element3** is present under **Diagram2**.

I have **cut** **Element1** which is under Package1 from Project browser and Pasted it under Package2.
Element1 is pasted correctly under Package2, but **Element1 Diagram object** is still present under Diagram1 instead of Diagram2.

Is there any way while using EA cut/paste feature along with selected Element, Diagram Object should also get cut from Diagram1 and get pasted under Diagram2 similar to Project browser.

Comment: Why would moving elements between packages move them between diagrams? if your diagrams purpose is to show what is in a package, consider using package elements in your diagrams instead

Comment: If I cut an Element then along with an Element, Diagram object should also get pasted into the Selected Package.

Comment: No, not possible. I don't know if it's possible to capture Windoze keyboard keys and steal them from the main application. That would be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

For customized application as mentioned above .
Best way to do that is to use script and it very easy 
[Example scripts available ]
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/the_scripter_window.html

Let me know if you need in scripting

Comment: I was trying with Add-In (C#) but I was not to achieve this, it would be great help if you please provide me the script to achieve above mentioned issue.

Comment: There are two ways to do that 1 is as you said creating add in using c# other way is by using internal script.Go to tool-scripts you will see lot of example script ..I will try to make the script in free time